How long would a post-apocalyptic space colony take to recover modern levels of technology?
I'm currently working on a little project. The scenario I'm asking about here is not a "lost colony" type scenario, but instead where a series of space colonies (primarily, but not exclusively) on the moon have been established by the near future (by an accelerated Cold War Space Race or something), and are the last remaining survivors of a apocalypse on Earth that wipes out the population on the planet. (I'm thinking massive nuclear war + asteroid impact, in quick succession, but still working on it.)
The lunar colonies populations in total are about  ~150,000 "original" colonists, plus another ~100,000 refugees that were evacuated in the first couple years after the apocalypse. The colonies have some manufacturing capability, mainly confined to refining lunar rock and ice into usable materials, manufacture of ship and habitat parts, fuels, farming, and the like. So not advanced things like large microchip fabs, advanced pharmaceuticals, etc.
Could the colonies conceivably survive with the cutoff of supplies from Earth? If they could, how long would it take for them to reach a modern* level of technology again? Decades? Centuries?
How far might they have to fall back, or "gear down" their technology, as the original, advanced equipment like the computers fail? Would the technological development be limited mainly by the small population, or something else, like lost knowledge?
*I know that tech development would be uneven, with some, more relevant sectors advancing faster than others, but I'm using "modern" as a rough sort of benchmark, for a similar level of sophistication in manufacturing and particularly, computer technology.
Thanks!

Depends on what supplies they're relying on.

It relies on 2 things: Do they have the knowledge of how to build the things they currently cannot and do they have precision engineering? Before I can answer - I need to know that.

We have been asked this question a lot. ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], and many more). @TheDemonLord is 100% correct, but note that 99.9% of all human technology was invented in the last 150 years. How long it takes requires people, resources, opportunity, and a starting point - but it's rarely more than 150 years.

No petrochemicals.  Not enough water to both make ship fuel and sustain life.  Probably barely enough carbon to sustain an ecosystem without regular resupplies of nutrients.  The colony is going to die.


The colonies have some manufacturing capability, mainly confined to refining lunar rock and ice into usable materials, manufacture of ship and habitat parts, fuels, farming, and the like. So not advanced things like large microchip fabs, advanced pharmaceuticals, etc.

They won't last long enough to restart civilization. Space relies massively on electronics to monitor and control everything, survival systems included. Without incoming spares for all that electronic equipment any failure will be fatal, and also any electronics-dependent in-situ production will stop or considerably dumb down.
Space, the Moon included, is a harsh environment. While we have examples of devices surviving decades to space, we designed them for that because no maintenance mission was possible. On the other hand, a lunar settlement (with the mirage of supplies available with just few weeks lead time) would probably not put much money into "decades long space proof" electronics. Economics and efficiency are required for large projects of any kind.
As soon as all the electronics start withering, so would the colony: wait for the first epidemic of typhoid fever following a failure in the waste management system with insufficient medicine to cure everyone and see what a happy environment the colony becomes.

Yeah, a chip fabrication plant costs several billion dollars, more if you want it hardened for space. That's not something 100k people can realistically support.

But you can store a LOT of microchips in a shipping crate.
Also, the extreme cost of microchip manufacturing is about manufacturing the cutting edge chips that are competitive on todays earths global market on a huge scale.
Machinery for manufacturing tech that is two decades behind, on a small scale, should be MUCH more manageable, and still be good enough for most applications.

@LazyLizard But you can't store a lot of people who know how to use those microchips into a shipping crate. Those microchips will degrade over time. The few people with technical knowhow and good problem-solving skills will be focused on keeping the rest of the population alive with as simple of technology as possible, not on advancing technology.
